# Shell script that runs only if previous command succeeds, or only if some files are present

Tags: linux, bash, apache, shell, jar

I have set of shell scripts which run in **Apache** server from **cgi-bin**.
The first script triggers the second, the second triggers the third, and so on. Except on a particular script, say the 10th script... it executes a *jar* file that needs certain input from a **for** loop.  When I run the scripts everything works fine, except this *jar* file.  The *jar* file can't come out of the loop; it shows it is still executing, but in the background the task will be finished.  And as it is not coming out of loop, it is not triggering the next command and script.

`10.sh` code:

```
#!/bin/bash
source variable.sh
for ((ib=1; ib<=9; ib++))
do
    in1=$(cat /input.txt | cut -d  " " -f1 | sed -n ''$ib'p')
    in2=$(cat input2.txt | cut -d  " " -f1 | sed -n ''$ib'p')
    java -jar javatool.jar -nogui -i $in2 -b $in1 -outdir /$in1
done 
echo '10th script done'
./11.sh
```

The same script works in a local terminal but not from a server. I have checked the permissions, everything is fine.

Later I tried putting "**&**" after the **java** to push it into the background, which executed the next script. But the next script needs the output from that *jar* too.

Edit 1
The java programming is still not coming out of loop when I put **&**

Is there any way to make the next script execute only if certain files are found in a directory, and if not wait for 2 minutes, and check for directory, and execute (it should not exit, it should check the folder again and again till files are present).
Is there any way to do it?
Or is there any way to complete the loop of that jar file?

Answer (score 2):

You could append this to your script

```
while [ ! -f outfile_frm_script10 ];
do
    sleep 1;
done;
echo '10th script done'
./11.sh
```